# I can't dismiss ProgressDialog when webvView has completed loading the webpage

Tags: android, multithreading, webview, progressdialog

I want to dismiss the ProgressDialog when webview completed loading the webpage, it isn't working for me. Here is my code :

```
    package com.mcc.ghurbo;


import java.security.PublicKey;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class GhurboActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        final WebView mywebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        final ProgressDialog p=new ProgressDialog(GhurboActivity.this);
        p.show(GhurboActivity.this, "", "Loading...");





        Thread loading=new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                        try {

                              mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

                          } 
                        //end of try
                        catch(Exception e ){
                             e.printStackTrace();
                       }// end of catch
                        finally{
                            p.dismiss();
                        }//end of finally
              }//end of run
     };//end of thread
     loading.start();





}
```

Please help me as early as possible. I can't proceed my further work without solving  this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach to show the progress Dialog with webView

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                // Start PROGRESS DIALOG
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            //HIDE PROGRESS DIALOG LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
          }

        });
```

It will surely help u